# Can I haunt people as a ghost?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have 2 extra philter of the phantom potions from a quest that make me appear spectral for 30 seconds.  Are there any practical uses for this?  Can I use it to scare other people for some benefit or use it to walk by undead safely?

Also, is it possible to make more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The potion seems to be a cosmetic and nothing more. I have yet not discovered any use for it, other than making you look fancy.

Regarding your question if making more is possible; No, or as far as I have explored the alchemy possibilities, I haven't found an option to do so. The only way to obtain some are by killing Wyndelius in the [Shroud Hearth Barrow](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Shroud_Hearth_Barrow).

Comment: that's a shame.

Comment: where did you get the potion? you can use it for talk to the headless horseman

Answer (score 14):

Any crimes you commit while in Spectral form will not go towards your bounty, so you can break the law without punishment.

Answer (score 6):

As to your second question...

I am unsure whether this is intended or a bug/glitch, but he seems to restock the potion if you are able to pickpocket and walk away safely.  However, you might need high levels of sneak and few brief invisibility potions.

Comment: that's good to know

Answer (score 1):

Well I haven't found a mod that makes the potion brewable at an alchemy table. But took a similar interested and looked for enchantments that might do the same. Here's what I came up with.

```
playerenchantobject (ObjectID) (Spectral Effect) (Howl of Fear)

playerenchantobject 000877B1 00103647 000CF797

000CF796 : Werewolf Fear Howl 1 (HowlWerewolfFearEffect1)
000CF797 : Werewolf Fear Howl 2 (HowlWerewolfFearEffect2)
000CF798 : Werewolf Fear Howl 3 (HowlWerewolfFearEffect3)
```

The object itself can be anything you wear in the game, or any ring for that matter. I went for a Silver Ruby one myself.  But I admit to being a little stuck about spells that make people flee in terror when they simply see you. The Werewolf effect is the best I could find that isn't spit out as invalid in the console.

I'm open if anyone knows an enchantment ID for people going hostile and running level confidence.

Answer (score 0):

i just leave with the stuff and wait 2 weeks then go grab another